# Decoding charaters retreive from API request

Tags: python, api, decode

I'm trying to create a Discord bot that will make an API request to retreive a list of usernames. I've mostly got it working but my only issue is that the usernames can contain emojis and other non-ASCII characters so some of the usernames are not being dispalyed correctly.
For example очень is displayed as Ğ¾Ñ‡ĞµĞ½ÑŒ

This is an excerpt of my current code:

```
a = requests.get("http://<url>/usernames.json", headers={"X-API-Key":"key"})
b = json.loads(a.text)
print(b)
```

Comment: How do you want очень to be represented as?

Comment: did you try `a.json()`?

Comment: @JeniDave очень is the username of the user so I would like it to be displayed as очень, at the moment it's represented as ĞµĞ½ÑŒ

Comment: @balderman I hadn't tried it before. After adding it, it appears to work now. Thanks for your help

Comment: `'Ğ¾Ñ‡ĞµĞ½ÑŒ'.encode('cp1254').decode('utf-8')` returns `'очень'`…